# I assume there is a simple solution to a few errors regarding "was not declared in this scope"

Tags: c++, stack, queue

I'm working on a project where I have to implement a queue as a stack. I've written the code for my QueueAsAStack.h and .cpp file, and I'm getting errors on the project4.cpp driver file provided by my professor. He has provided QueueInterface.h as well as the implementation for the stack, I just need to implement the QueueAsAStack and PriorityQueueHasAStack.

I have not yet coded anything for PriorityQueueHasAStack yet, but I don't think that's the problem.

All errors I am getting are coming from project4.cpp, but I'll include them here:

```
project4.cpp: In function 'void testQueue(int*, int)':
project4.cpp:19:2: error: 'QueueInterface' was not declared in this scope
  QueueInterface<int>* theQueue = new QueueAsAStack<int>();
  ^
project4.cpp:19:17: error: expected primary-expression before 'int'
  QueueInterface<int>* theQueue = new QueueAsAStack<int>();
                 ^
project4.cpp:22:3: error: 'theQueue' was not declared in this scope
   theQueue->enqueue(arr[i]);
   ^
project4.cpp:25:7: error: 'theQueue' was not declared in this scope
   if (theQueue->isEmpty()) {
       ^
project4.cpp:30:14: error: 'theQueue' was not declared in this scope
   testResult(theQueue->peekFront(), arr[i]);
              ^
project4.cpp:34:9: error: 'theQueue' was not declared in this scope
  delete theQueue;
         ^
project4.cpp: In function 'void testPriorityQueue(int*, int)':
project4.cpp:38:2: error: 'PriorityQueueInterface' was not declared in this scope
  PriorityQueueInterface<int>* pQueue = new PriorityQueueHasAStackedQueue<int>();
  ^
project4.cpp:38:25: error: expected primary-expression before 'int'
  PriorityQueueInterface<int>* pQueue = new PriorityQueueHasAStackedQueue<int>();
                         ^
project4.cpp:43:3: error: 'pQueue' was not declared in this scope
   pQueue->enqueue(arr[i]);
   ^
project4.cpp:50:7: error: 'pQueue' was not declared in this scope
   if (pQueue->isEmpty()) {
       ^
project4.cpp:55:14: error: 'pQueue' was not declared in this scope
   testResult(pQueue->peek(), sorted[i]);
              ^
project4.cpp:59:9: error: 'pQueue' was not declared in this scope
  delete pQueue;
```

Here is project4.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include "PriorityQueueHasAStackedQueue.cpp"

int failures = 0;

void testResult(int result, int expected) {
    if (result != expected) {
        std::cout << "test FAILED: expected(" << expected << ") but result(" << result << ")" << std::endl;
        failures++;
    }
}

void testQueue(int* arr, int n) {
    QueueInterface<int>* theQueue = new QueueAsAStack<int>();

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        theQueue->enqueue(arr[i]);

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (theQueue->isEmpty()) {
            std::cout << "test FAILED: queue unexpectedly empty" << std::endl;
            failures++;
            break;
        }
        testResult(theQueue->peekFront(), arr[i]);
        theQueue->dequeue();
    }

    delete theQueue;
}

void testPriorityQueue(int* arr, int n) {
    PriorityQueueInterface<int>* pQueue = new PriorityQueueHasAStackedQueue<int>();
    int sorted[n];

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        sorted[i] = arr[i];
        pQueue->enqueue(arr[i]);
    }

    std::sort(sorted, sorted + n);
    std::reverse(sorted, sorted + n);

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (pQueue->isEmpty()) {
            std::cout << "test FAILED: queue unexpectedly empty" << std::endl;
            failures++;
            break;
        }
        testResult(pQueue->peek(), sorted[i]);
        pQueue->dequeue();
    }

    delete pQueue;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int arr1[1] = { 5 };
    int arr2[2] = { 3, 3 };
    int arr6[6] = { 5, 8, 9, 5, 1, 0 };

    testQueue(arr1, 1);
    testPriorityQueue(arr1, 1);

    testQueue(arr2, 2);
    testPriorityQueue(arr2, 2);

    testQueue(arr6, 6);
    testPriorityQueue(arr6, 6);

    if (failures == 0)
        std::cout << "ALL TESTS PASSED" << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << failures << " TESTS FAILED" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

QueueAsAStack.h:

```
#ifndef QUEUE_AS_A_STACK_
#define QUEUE_AS_A_STACK_

#include "QueueInterFace.h"
#include "LinkedStack.h"

template<class ItemType>
class QueueAsAStack : public QueueInterface<ItemType>, private LinkedStack<ItemType>
{
    QueueAsAStack<int>* q = new QueueAsAStack<int>();
    QueueAsAStack<int>* temp = new QueueAsAStack<int>();

    bool isEmpty() const;
    bool enqueue(const ItemType& newEntry);
    bool dequeue();
    ItemType peekFront() const; 
};

#endif
```

And QueueAsAStack.cpp:

```
#include "QueueAsAStack.h"
#include "QueueInterface.h"

template<class ItemType>
QueueAsAStack<ItemType>::isEmpty() const
{
    return q.peek() == nullptr;
}

template<class ItemType>
QueueAsAStack<ItemType>::enqueue(const ItemType& newEntry)
{
    q.push(newEntry);

    return true;
}

template<class ItemType>
QueueAsAStack<ItemType>::dequeue()
{
    // While queue is not empty, push everything onto temp
    while(!q.isEmpty()){
        temp.push(q.peek());
        q.pop();
    }

    temp.pop(); // Take off the first item, or the front of the queue

    // Flip it all back to queue
    while(!temp.isEmpty())
        q.push(temp.peek());

    return true;
}

template<class ItemType>
QueueAsAStack<ItemType>::peekFront() const
{
    QueueAsAStack<int> peekedItem;

    // Flip everything over to temp
    while(!q.isEmpty())
        temp.push(q.peek());

    peekedItem = temp.peek(); // Store front of queue in peekedItem

    // Flip it all back again
    while(!temp.isEmpty())
        q.push(temp.peek());

    return peekedItem;
}
```

Thank you.

Edit: Forgot QueueInterFace.h

```
#ifndef QUEUE_INTERFACE_
#define QUEUE_INTERFACE_

template<class ItemType>
class QueueInterface

{
public:
   /** Sees whether this queue is empty.
    @return True if the queue is empty, or false if not. */
   virtual bool isEmpty() const = 0;

   /** Adds a new entry to the back of this queue.
    @post If the operation was successful, newEntry is at the 
       back of the queue.
    @param newEntry  The object to be added as a new entry.
    @return True if the addition is successful or false if not. */
   virtual bool enqueue(const ItemType& newEntry) = 0;

   /** Removes the front of this queue.
    @post If the operation was successful, the front of the queue 
       has been removed.
    @return True if the removal is successful or false if not. */
   virtual bool dequeue() = 0;

   /** Returns the front of this queue.
    @pre The queue is not empty.
    @post The front of the queue has been returned, and the
       queue is unchanged.
    @return The front of the queue. */
   virtual ItemType peekFront() const = 0;

   /** Destroys object and frees memory allocated by object. */
   virtual ~QueueInterface() { }
}; // end QueueInterface
#endif
```

Comment: Do not include .cpp files. Include instead the appropriate header.

Comment: @Yunnosch Sorry, forgot to add. It's added.

Comment: add to project4.cpp : #include "QueueAsAStack.h"

Comment: I don't think I can because that is a file that my professor provided to us. I don't think I am allowed to edit it, but I'll add that and see if it's fixed. Thanks! @Alexander

Comment: Since project4.cpp has #include "PriorityQueueHasAStackedQueue.cpp", could I do #include "QueueAsAStack.h" in PriorityQueueHasAStackedQueue.cpp and that would fix it? Adding it to project4.cpp seemed to fix those errors, however I still have some more because I haven't written the priority queue yet.

Comment: @Sam you will have more issues after fixing this one. your QueueAsAStack.cpp contains a template class definition but usually, it should be in the header

Comment: @Sam 
you can include it into PriorityQueueHasAStackedQueue.cpp as far as it is included in your cpp. but be aware the including cpp files is a bad and dangerous practice

Comment: @Alexander I'll have to ask my professor about it lol thanks